# Click DirectX Button from Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, button, directx, click

I have a windows forms application where I would like to find the handle of a DirectX application, find a DirectX button in that window, and Click it.

Is this possible, and if so, where is the best place to start?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really not possible.

Unlike Windows Forms, a "DirectX Button" has no distinct windows handle.  You don't actually "click" a button in a DirectX window, but rather send a mouse click to the entire DirectX window, and allow the application to do its own hit testing to "click" the "button" (which is just a graphic).

The closest you could do would be to send a mouse click to a location within the window - however, finding the location of a "button" could be very difficult.

Comment: Oh, Well. Then that's too much work for the simple task I was hoping to accomplish. Thanks though ;)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it isn't too difficult if that is the case. A DX object can receive an click if you can isolate the object with the mouse through a reversal system, depending if it is 3D-based or 2D-based. 2D is using masking effects, and 3D adds on to translate to and from 2D/3D based space on certain properties utilized in vector calculus.

Pretty much from logical space, in 3D, a slice of the 3D object is mapped to 2D space, which is then mapped to camera space, which is then rendered. Crude, there is much more to it then that, but I'm keeping it as simple as it can be. Now the task is to find the 2D volume/per-pixel location, translate a copy of the 2D render of a 3D object on an image that will be/is already a DeviceContext for the monitor to show () to a map, and unionize a clickable object (which will run the intended code, just as a button should) to the 2D map object copy.

In other words, find where in the screen the object is rendered and generate a clickable mask over the rendered portion of the screen. Whether it is a bitmap mask, or a polygon mask, or a cube mask, or any other shape you can mathematically create; so long as the 2D clickable object actually interfaces with the mouse position and state in an constant-update system.

For example, say that application is full screen, that the resolution is 800 x 600 (keeping it simple, it could be anything), and that the object you wish to be able to interact, that is rendered in a context that doesn't permit it of it's own accord (*1), and that the rendered object shows a rectangle. Lets say that is the point of it, and the system you use for the translation outputs a Rectangle (C#.NET code, yea, but it's just an example, there are better floating around). So we can say that the mask rectangle coordinates are identical to to the rendered object coordinates.

So let's say: "Rectangle mask = new Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 100); // X starting point, Y starting point, Length, Width." Pretty self-explanatory. Add a per-frame cursor position compared with mask positions, will indicate if the cursor is above the mask, and with extra coding, can indicated if the cursor clicked (or other events) while being within the mask's range.

So let's say the button opens the main menu. And an event happens, particularly a "MouseClick" event, while the cursor hotspot is at Point(125, 200). Which of course was in the range of the mask. In this instance, through all that trivial code, opens the main menu. It is easy to add new clickable objects within this system if it is done right.

Yes, other, easier ways exist. But from them all, this is one of the more dynamic and flexible systems. Uses range from the cash you get as loot in a game that you have to click to pick up, to the UI, to the menu's, to anything clickable. The range isn't in just games, either. Custom UI designers who like to reinvent the wheel can and have taken advantage of similar systems, such as myself, like to define every aspect from the microcode to the macrocode. Precisely, to define the macrocode as it is needed, as it is expected and without unnecessary bloat through microcode management. Not saying I like microcode, as it can be way too bloody finicky, and often times, is. Worth it for the few hundred FPS you get from streamlining it right (the first time), though... >:-D

*1 = (predictable  in 3D Rendering models, from the point of view Rendering is not Modifying (which seems to be including object selection (through the mouse/cursor position and all that), which is essentially what your looking for) and as such not included (directly). Through translation it becomes possible, with the finest precision if done right. Further to that, DirectX, OpenGL, and others like, are defaultly Renderers.)

Comment: Very interesting, though complex for my brain. If you could provide an example it would be helpful ;)